# Amazon product advertising API always returning undefined as result

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am trying to use amazon product advertising API lookup product details for products in my DB. However, the response is always undefined. Am I doing anything wrong ?

```
var amazon = require('amazon-product-api');

var client = amazon.createClient({
  awsId: "my aws id",
  awsSecret: "my secret key",
  awsTag: "my aws tag"
});

client.itemLookup({  
    responseGroup: 'Images,ItemAttributes,Offers,EditorialReview',
    IdType: 'ASIN',
    ItemId: "B00UTKTX36"
}).then(function (results){
    console.log("results", results);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err.Error[0].Message);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things -
1. `B00UTKTX36` is not a valid ASIN anymore (atleast as of now) [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00UTKTX36](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UTKTX36)
2. `ItemLookup` operation on ASINs should not contain `SearchIndex` parameter. So comment this line https://github.com/t3chnoboy/amazon-product-api/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L57 in your `node_modules/amazon-product-api/lib/utils.js` and you are good to go.